# How can I solve my issue with Ngx doc viewer with office viewer and google viewer?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, ngx-doc-viewer

I am using `ngx-doc-viewer` for previewing Microsoft office files. The viewer I am taking is office, which results in an issue.

When I preview PowerPoint (`ppt`) file, it is showing spreadsheet; however, this behavior is not constant. Every-time I upload any office type file, it gives wrong preview.

*Note: I am not using google viewer because of maximum size limitation of 25 Mb.*

PFA the code below:

```html
<ngx-doc-viewer [url]="uploadedFileUrl
                [viewer]="file?.type?.includes('officedocument')?'office':'url'">
```

Thank you for your help.